# python group file names by exact string

Tags: python

I am trying to group file names by specific ID, here is what I have so far:

```
(ccc)khine@dhegdheer:~/Sandboxes/Business/continentalclothing.com$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> cropped = ['ccc-public,assets/cropped/low_res/EP01.jpg', 'ccc-public,assets/cropped/low_res/EP01L.jpg', 'ccc-public,assets/cropped/low_res/EP01_10.jpg', 'ccc-public,assets/cropped/low_res/EP01_20_1.jpg', 'ccc-public,assets/cropped/low_res/EP01_21_1.jpg', 'ccc-public,assets/cropped/low_res/EP02.jpg', 'ccc-public,assets/cropped/low_res/EP03.jpg', 'ccc-public,assets/cropped/low_res/EP03V.jpg']
>>> styles = ['EP01', 'EP01L', 'EP02', 'EP03', 'EP03V']
>>> def get_cropped(style):
...     cropped_images = []
...     matching = [key for key in cropped if style in key.rsplit('/', 1)[1]]
...     for x in matching:
...             cropped_images.append(x)
...     return cropped_images
... 
>>> for style in styles:
...     get_s3_images = get_cropped(style)
...     for x in get_s3_images:
...             print x
... 
assets/cropped/low_res/EP01.jpg
assets/cropped/low_res/EP01L.jpg
assets/cropped/low_res/EP01_10.jpg
assets/cropped/low_res/EP01_20_1.jpg
assets/cropped/low_res/EP01_21_1.jpg
assets/cropped/low_res/EP01L.jpg
assets/cropped/low_res/EP02.jpg
assets/cropped/low_res/EP03.jpg
assets/cropped/low_res/EP03V.jpg
assets/cropped/low_res/EP03V.jpg
```

What is the correct way to extract all paths that contain EP01, so I get a list like

```
    "/assets/cropped/low_res/EP01.jpg",
    "/assets/cropped/low_res/EP01_10.jpg",
    "/assets/cropped/low_res/EP01_20_1.jpg",
    "/assets/cropped/low_res/EP01_21_1.jpg"
```

excluding `"/assets/cropped/low_res/EP01L.jpg",` entry and for `EP01L` to return, just `<Key: ccc-public,assets/cropped/low_res/EP01L.jpg>`

Any advice much appreciated

Comment: What is the type of objects in `get_s3_images` list and how do you get the paths from them?

Comment: Why `EP01L` is not included?

Comment: EP01L is a different style ID, so i want it grouped separately

Comment: If EP01L is different, you need to properly order the IDs upfront - IDs that contain other IDs (as EP01L) need to be filtered out *before* the EP01-filtering, because otherwise you get false positives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression matching just the substring you need, e.g. `r'.*/EP01(?:_|\b)'`:

```
import re

def get_cropped(style):
    rex = re.compile(r'.*/%s(?:\b|_)' % style)
    cropped_images = [img for img in cropped if rex.match(img)]
    return cropped_images

for style in styles:
    print '\nStyle:', style
    get_s3_images = get_cropped(style)
    for x in get_s3_images:
        print x
```

Instead of the list-comprehension, you can also use the built-in function `filter`:

```
def get_cropped(style):
    rex = re.compile(r'.*/%s(?:\b|_)' % style)
    cropped_images = filter(rex.match, cropped)
    return cropped_images
```

**Update**

Another possible solution involves the standard module `itertools`:

```
import re
import itertools

rex = re.compile(r'.*/(.*?)[_.]')
for (style, images) in itertools.groupby(cropped, lambda s: rex.match(s).group(1)):
    print '\nStyle:', style
    for img in images:
        print ' ', img
```

The *lambda* function extracts the image style from the image path, returning the characters after the last slash and up to the first underscore or dot. Then `itertools.groupby` makes use of this information to group all paths listed in `cropped` by their styles.